# HTML + CSS navigation bar highlighting current page

Tags: html, css

So I have been working on a website and now want to have the navigation bar highlight the current page you are on, I tried searching the site for answered questions but they all had very different looking code from mine so I thought I'd ask.

Right now I have a class formatting a list and tried to add a class for the homepage list item:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">placeholder</a></li>
</ul>
```

The css part looks like this:

```
.menu
{
background-color: #91BD4A;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.menu ul 
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
font-size:0;
}

.menu li 
{
display: inline;
list-style: none;
}
.menu a:link, a:visited 
{
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -6px;
width: 140.7px;
color: #000 !important;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #91BD4A !important;
}

.menu a:hover, a:active
{
text-decoration: underline;
background-color: #91BD4A;
}
.active, a.active
{
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kubynsu3/)
Here I tried to add a class for the first list item the home page but it does not make a difference, is there a way to do this without altering my code a lot`?

Comment: You can do with jQuery - https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/stylesheets/how-do-i-style-active-link-with-javascript-and-css

Comment: You cannot do this **automatically** with CSS as it cannot detect which page you are on. This is usually the realm of Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use JavaScript or jQuery to do this

example

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.navigation
{
    background:#fff;
}
ul.navigation li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.navigation li a.on
{
    background:yellow;
    padding:2px 6px;
}
</style>
```

JQ

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var $page = jQuery.url.attr("file");
    $('ul.navigation li a').each(function(){
        var $href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ( ($href == $page) || ($href == '') ) {
            $(this).addClass('on');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('on');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

demo is here 
http://www.kevinleary.net/wp-samples/jquery-current-navigation/solutions.html

for more information

http://www.kevinleary.net/highlighting-the-current-page-with-php-jquery/

i hope this will help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kubynsu3/4/)**

```
.menu {
    background-color: #91BD4A;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:0;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu li a:link, .menu li a:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -6px;
    width: 140.7px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #91BD4A;
}
.menu li.active > a {
    text-decoration: underline;
     background-color: #999;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Through CSS you can do like this manually in all the pages to highlight current page, If you want to give this dynamicaaly you need Jquery..