# What is the name of dynamic page identifier in websites

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, sass

Hello I'm trying to build a react component as the one below:
[image]

but I don't know what is the name of such component, in order to search more about it.

If anyone knows anything about it please help.

Answer (score 1):

I would call this a navigation bar where the current page is highlighted.

Maybe you can find some info here: [HTML + CSS navigation bar highlighting current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073190/html-css-navigation-bar-highlighting-current-page)